# Textview setCompoundDrawables dont change or show

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ListView with a custom  list item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:maxWidth="32dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="24sp" >

    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now Eclipse warning me with `This tag and its children can be replaced by one <TextView/> and a compound drawable`. everything work fine but i hate warnings now  i've changed the view to.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/unstarred" >

    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

but the image is not showing, can tell me what is wrong in the layout, this is my adapter

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category> {

    private Context mContext;
    private int mLayoutResourceId;
    private Category mCategories[] = null;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Category[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);

        mContext = context;
        mCategories = data;
        mLayoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        Holder holder = null;

        if(null == row) {               
            row = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.mIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
            holder.mTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(android.R.id.title);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) row.getTag();
        }

       // obviously only one is used at a time
       // First layout
       final Category category = mCategories[position];
       holder.mTitle.setText(category.getName());
       holder.mIcon
          .setImageResource(category.getStarred() == 1 ? R.drawable.starred : R.drawable.unstarred);            

       // Second layout
       final Category category = mCategories[position];
       final Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(category.getStarred() == 1 ? R.drawable.starred : R.drawable.unstarred);
       holder.mTitle.setText(category.getName());
       holder.mTitle.setCompoundDrawables(icon, null, null, null);

        return row;
    }       
}

public static class Holder {
    ImageView mIcon;
    TextView mTitle;        
}
```

the problem is: **the image is not showing**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I changed `setCompoundDrawables` for `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` and finally works

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but yet relevant (at least to me ;-)), so maybe someone else is looking for the answer.

None of the answers have actually described what the issue is, although the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27143533/882251) by user4294815 came pretty close.

The reason why this happens is because `#setBounds()` hasn't been called on your icon and so it will never have any size except for `width = 0` and `height = 0`.

Also if you have a look at the documentation for `#setCompoundDrawables()` it actually states that you need to call `#setBounds()` on the `Drawable` before setting the `Drawable`:

> ```
> /**
>  * Sets the Drawables (if any) to appear to the left of, above, to the
>  * right of, and below the text. Use {@code null} if you do not want a
>  * Drawable there. The Drawables must already have had
>  * {@link Drawable#setBounds} called.
>  * <p>
>  * Calling this method will overwrite any Drawables previously set using
>  * {@link #setCompoundDrawablesRelative} or related methods.
>  *
>  * @attr ref android.R.styleable#TextView_drawableLeft
>  * @attr ref android.R.styleable#TextView_drawableTop
>  * @attr ref android.R.styleable#TextView_drawableRight
>  * @attr ref android.R.styleable#TextView_drawableBottom
>  */
> ```

Now to fix this, you can either call `#setBounds()` on your `Drawable` or if you're not working with the `Drawable` directly, you'd have to use either `#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()` or `#setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds()`. The latter is more appropriate today, as it doesn't use `left` and `right` namings, but uses `start` and `end`, so the icons will be set relative to the reading direction.

I know that rkmax's own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15710264/882251) answered the question, or at least provided the solution, but sometimes that's not enough - text explaining the issue is more appropriate in my opinion and adds clarification to the next person looking at this question.

Comment: Awesome answer, although `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` was working for me but not on android 4.4. When I read your explanation it does make sense for relativity bounds. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Add:

```
icon.setBounds(0, 0, your icon width, your icon height);
```

before:

```
holder.mTitle.setCompoundDrawables(icon, null, null, null);
```

or:

```
holder.mTitle.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(category.getStarred() == 1 ? R.drawable.starred : R.drawable.unstarred, null, null, null);
```

instead.